# UITextField how to remove Strong Password overlay

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios14

[image]

As shown in the picture, I am dealing with a "Strong Password" overlay in a secured UITextField. What is the correct way to handle this? One time the overlay appears, I can not make it dissapear or auto generate a strong password.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to disable this entirely.

I ran into this same issue in the simulator. To get around it, make sure the software keyboard is showing. Then it should show you the prompt so you can "Choose My Own Password".[image]

Comment: Thanks Ben! So you didn´t face this issue running an app in a real device, did you?